# is 'if top==None:top=1' correct

Tags: python

I don't understand why the `top` variable in the `append` function is greyed out.
No matter what I do, the value of `top` stays None.
[This is the output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/i1oo8.png). I also tried using 0 instead of None and I still have the same problem. I've included the code below.

```py
top = None
stack = []
def append(a, top):
  stack.append(a)
  if top == None:
    top = 1 
  else:
    top += 1 
def pop(top):
  if top == None:
    print('underflow error encountered')
  else:
    print('the popped element is:', poppedele)
    print(top)
while True:
  kk = input('wat do you want to do ....')
  if kk == '1':
    a = input('enter the element to append')
    append(a,  top)
    print(stack, top)
  elif:
    pop(top)
    print(stack, top)
  else:
    break
```

Here's a screenshot of what it looks like:

[image: ![Code]

Comment: you have to paste your code and  data here

Comment: Paste a minimal reproducible example here, what you expected, and what you got.

Comment: Add a ’return (a,top)’ at the end of your func, and ’a,top=append(a,top)’ when you call it

Comment: I did try it but unfortunately i came to know that stack overflow does not have an option to past python code. correct me if I'm wrong

Comment: @LumberJack I tried it but unfortunately it does not work

Comment: The question cannot be answered at the moment, but your problem seems to be that you are modifying the `top` function parameter and you are trying to modify the `top` global variable. Try to e.g. change the name of the global variable or the *append* function parameter.

Comment: Thank you @Aarni joensuu. It worked 
I used the global keyword and it worked

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @aarni joensuu.
Turns out I should add global top in those functions only then the change will be made to the overall variable.